# Create gridview datatable/source code behind error

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

On my page, there are two gridviews where data are added to them dynamically using code behind. There are no problems with the code as far as I can see, the first gridview runs fine, but as soon as I want to add data to the second it gives me the error of:

```
    Column 'LabourType' does not belong to table Table1
```

This is the error it gives when I initialize the labour grid first (Everything goes through fine). However, if I initialize the PartsGrid first it gives me the same error, just with the first column name of the parts grid.

This is what I have done in the Page_Load:

```
    DataTable dtParts;
    DataTable dtLabour;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            PopulateCustomers();

            dtLabour = new DataTable();
            MakeDataTableLabour();
            EmptyDataStringLabour();
            this.gvLabour.EditIndex = -1;

            dtParts = new DataTable();
            MakeDataTableParts();
            EmptyDataStringParts();
            this.gvParts.EditIndex = -1;
        }
        else
        {
            dtLabour = (DataTable)ViewState["DataTable"];
            dtParts = (DataTable)ViewState["DataTable"];
        }

        ViewState["DataTable"] = dtLabour;
        ViewState["DataTable"] = dtParts;
    }
```

Can anybody please tell me if I am doing anything wrong? Or how can I solve this to allow both grids for data to be added dynamically? Thanks in advance

EDIT - More Data

For the Parts Grid this is how I create and add data to the datatable:

```
    private void MakeDataTableParts()
    {
        dtParts.Columns.Add("Units");
        dtParts.Columns.Add("PartNo");
        dtParts.Columns.Add("Description");
        dtParts.Columns.Add("CostPrice");
    }

    private void AddToDataTableParts()
    {
        DataRow drParts = dtParts.NewRow();
        drParts["Units"] = txtUnits.Text.Trim();
        drParts["PartNo"] = txtPartNo.Text.Trim();
        drParts["Description"] = txtDescription.Text.Trim();
        drParts["CostPrice"] = txtCostPrice.Text.Trim();
        dtParts.Rows.Add(drParts);
    }

     private void BindGridParts()
    {
        gvParts.DataSource = dtParts;
        gvParts.DataBind();
    }
```

And for the labour:

```
    private void MakeDataTableLabour()
    {
        dtLabour.Columns.Add("Units");
        dtLabour.Columns.Add("LabourType");
        dtLabour.Columns.Add("LabourCost");
    }

    private void AddToDataTableLabour()
    {
        DataRow drLabour = dtLabour.NewRow();
        drLabour["Units"] = txtLabourUnits.Text;
        drLabour["LabourType"] = lstLabourType.SelectedValue.ToString();
        drLabour["LabourCost"] = txtLabourCost.Text;
        dtLabour.Rows.Add(drLabour);
    }

     private void BindGridLabour()
    {
        gvLabour.DataSource = dtLabour;
        gvLabour.DataBind();
    }
```

This is how my gridviews are created in .aspx
Parts:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gvParts" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" CellPadding="8" CellSpacing="8" AllowPaging="false"
                                 Width="100%" OnPageIndexChanging="gvParts_PageIndexChanging" OnRowCommand="gvParts_RowCommand" 
                                     OnRowCancelingEdit="gvParts_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowEditing="gvParts_RowEditing" 
                                     OnRowUpdating="gvParts_RowUpdating" OnRowDeleting="gvParts_RowDeleting"  >
                                <emptydatatemplate>
                                    There are currently no parts listed.
                                </emptydatatemplate> 
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText=""> 
                                    <ItemTemplate> 
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEditParts" runat="server"CommandName="EditParts" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'>Edit</asp:LinkButton>
                                    </ItemTemplate> 
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText=""> 
                                    <ItemTemplate> 
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkRemoveParts" runat="server" CommandName="DeleteParts" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'>Remove</asp:LinkButton>
                                    </ItemTemplate> 
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                            <HeaderStyle CssClass="Grid" />
                            <RowStyle CssClass="rowStyle" />
                            <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt" />
                            <PagerStyle CssClass="pgr" />
                        </asp:GridView>
```

Labour:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gvLabour" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" CellPadding="8" CellSpacing="8" AllowPaging="false"
                             Width="100%" OnPageIndexChanging="gvLabour_PageIndexChanging" OnRowCommand="gvLabour_RowCommand" 
                                 OnRowCancelingEdit="gvLabour_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowEditing="gvLabour_RowEditing" 
                                 OnRowUpdating="gvLabour_RowUpdating" OnRowDeleting="gvLabour_RowDeleting"  >
                            <emptydatatemplate>
                                There are currently no labour listed.
                            </emptydatatemplate> 
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText=""> 
                                    <ItemTemplate> 
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEditLabour" runat="server"CommandName="EditLabour" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'>Edit</asp:LinkButton>
                                    </ItemTemplate> 
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText=""> 
                                    <ItemTemplate> 
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkRemoveLabour" runat="server" CommandName="DeleteLabour" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'>Remove</asp:LinkButton>
                                    </ItemTemplate> 
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                            <HeaderStyle CssClass="Grid" />
                            <RowStyle CssClass="rowStyle" />
                            <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt" />
                            <PagerStyle CssClass="pgr" />
                        </asp:GridView>
```

I'm binding the grids on the button click events (modal popop) as follows:

```
    protected void btnSubmitPart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddToDataTableParts();
        BindGridParts();
        ClearPartsToAddNewItem();
    }

    protected void btnSubmitLabour_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddToDataTableLabour();
        BindGridLabour();
        ClearLabourToAddNewItem();
    }
```

Comment: Could we see the MakeDataTable..() methods?

Comment: Where are you setting the datasource?

Comment: can you explain MakeDataTableLabour(); and  EmptyDataStringLabour(); methods?

Comment: Sorry but I still can't see any code that binds grid, you have some methods defined but never called them?

Comment: @Sruthi, I call these methods in the pageload to create the table so that when the Add Labour button click event is run it will add the row and bind the gridview. The emtyDataStringLabour is just to show a message when the page loaded (and not to show as nothing)...

Comment: @Anonymous, I have added to button click events of how they are binded....

Comment: your data tables must be flushing out because of postback

Answer (score 1):

Error is self explanatory. You have set column `LabourType` either as `DataField` or used this column in databing expression in one of your `GridView` but this column is not present in `DataSource`.

Comment: i agree with @Anonymous answer.